# Custom CiviCrm Fields in views

Tags: drupal-views

I have a Drupal View pulling in data for contacts from generic CiviCRM fields as well as Custom Fields. For some reason sometimes when I load the view the generic fields populate properly but the custom fields don't populate. Once I clear Caches, everything populates properly.

Users who log in see this view and cannot clear caches. Any idea how I can fix this?

See screenshot where I point out the populated fields (some are blocked for privacy) and look at the other fields that remain as a token

[image]